# Printing out Haskell's evaluation (rewriting) steps for educational/learning purposes. Is it possible?

Tags: debugging, haskell, evaluation

I describe this question by using an example from a book.

In Simon Thompson's book "HASKELL the craft of functional programming" on page 82 (see images below) are shown the evaluation steps for `fac 4`.

**QUESTION:**

Is it possible to use some tool or some "Haskell debugger" that would write out the evaluation steps that GHCi uses when it would evaluate the value of `fac 4` ?

Preferably in a human readable format, for educational and learning purposes.

It would be also good to have some automatic explanation for each evaluation step, for example which equation was used in the rewriting step.

My main purpose is to gain a deeper understanding of how the rewriting steps are carried out when I run simple educational Haskell example programs (like `fac`).

Is there a way to do this ? If yes, how ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [simple-reflect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-reflect) can do some of this. But while it's useful for simple stuff like lists and maps, it doesn't work for everything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes and No. I haven't seen a tool yet that does this line-by-line evaluation that is depicted in your textbook - mostly because a Haskell programm does no "rewriting" of expressions.

However, there is a tool that does visualize Haskell's actual evaluation strategy, step by step: [**`ghc-vis`**](http://felsin9.de/nnis/ghc-vis/). Instead of just evaluating the result and displaying it on the console like `ghci` does, it displays a graphical representation of the unevaluated result - and you can force the evaluation of it thunk by thunk, until you arrive at the primitive values and structures.

As an example of what it can do, here's the evaluation until the third list member of the infinite fibonacci sequence:

[image: 0, 1 and 1 are evaluated, the rest of the list is a thunk referring back to parts of the list itself]

<sub>Source: [examples section of the project website](http://felsin9.de/nnis/ghc-vis/#more_examples). You should have a look at all of them!</sub>

Comment: Can it deal with full Haskell? For example with type classes and Monads? I'd love to see the visualisation how state monads work in Brian Beckmans video lectures.

Comment: This might be even more educational than seeing the rewriting steps!

Comment: More specificallys, Brian Beckman's video lectures are here : http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Brian-Beckman-The-Zen-of-Expressing-State-The-State-Monad).

Comment: Yes, it can deal with arbitrary haskell structures. I don't think that they would be display differently just because a particular data structure is instance of a specific type class such as a monad, though - but I haven't tried myself yet.

Answer (score 11):

There is a tool called [Lambda bubble pop](http://chrisuehlinger.com/LambdaBubblePop/) where you can click on the expression to see how the expression is getting reduced. Note that the tool only supports Integers and Lists as of now, but nevertheless is a good educational tool.

Snapshot of the tool in action:

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. Does this support type classes ? Monads ? Algebraic Data Types ? Seems to crash Safari though.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that none of these more advanced concepts are implemented yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is a much-requested and highly useful feature — which, as best as I know, is not available anywhere. :-(

Comment: "Is it possible to do this?" "No." How does that not answer the question?

Comment: Of course it's possible to do this. There's no tool I know of that does it to my satisfaction, but there's no reason you couldn't write one.

Comment: There is _totally_ no reason why such a tool can't exist - I really hope somebody writes one!